# How IdTCPServer can send and receive answer from specific client using OnExecute

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I started playing with Indy TCPServer and TCPClient few weeks ago, and now, after lots of research and help from SOF experts (specially Mr. Lebeau), I can securely manage client connections and send a string message to a specific client. Here is a piece of the code:

```
type
  TClient = class(TObject)
  private
    FHost: string;                  
  public
    FQMsg: TIdThreadSafeStringList; // Message Queue
    constructor Create(const Host: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: TClient;
  LQueue: TStringList;
  WQueue: TStringList;
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler Do
  begin
    DefStringEncoding := TEncoding.UTF8;
    LQueue := nil;
    Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
    try
      WQueue := Client.FQMsg.Lock;
      try
        if (WQueue.Count > 0) then
        begin
          LQueue := TStringList.Create;
          LQueue.Assign(WQueue);
          WQueue.Clear;
        end;
      finally
        Client.FQMsg.Unlock;
      end;
      if (LQueue <> nil) then
        Write(LQueue);
    finally
      LQueue.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now it's time to go a step further, and try to receive an answer from the client. But suddenly I realize that I can't use the TCPServer's OnExecute event to send the message and receive answer at "same time"?? I am probably wrong, but this code isn't working, and I have no idea why...

```
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  RStr: string;
  Client: TClient;
  LQueue: TStringList;
  WQueue: TStringList;
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler Do
  begin
    DefStringEncoding := TEncoding.UTF8;
    // Send Cmd
    LQueue := nil;
    Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
    try
      WQueue := Client.FQMsg.Lock;
      try
        if (WQueue.Count > 0) then
        begin
          LQueue := TStringList.Create;
          LQueue.Assign(WQueue);
          WQueue.Clear;
        end;
      finally
        Client.FQMsg.Unlock;
      end;
      if (LQueue <> nil) then
        Write(LQueue);
    finally
      LQueue.Free;
    end;
    // Receive Data
    RStr := Trim(ReadLn);
    if (RStr <> '') then
    begin
      SyncLog(RStr);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I add this last part (ReadLn) together, the first part of the code do not work, I cannot send the message to client anymore :(

Please, anyone knows what I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `TIdTextEncoding.UTF8` instead of `TEncoding.UTF8` (or `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` if you upgrade to Indy 10.6+), and move the assignment of `DefStringEncoding` to the `OnConnect` event.  You only need to assign it once, not on every read/write.

Second, `ReadLn()` is a blocking method.  It does exit until a line of actually read, or a timeout/error occurs.  So, to do what you are attempting, you have to check for the existence of inbound data before you actually read it, so that you can timeout and Exit and let `OnExecute` loop back to check the queue again.

Try something like this:

```
type
  TClient = class(TObject)
  private
    FHost: string;                  
    FQMsg: TIdThreadSafeStringList; // Message Queue
  public
    constructor Create(const Host: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property QMsg: TIdThreadSafeStringList read FQMsg;
  end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: TClient;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8;
  ...
  Client := TClient.Create;
  ...
  AContext.Data := Client;
  ...
 end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  RStr: string;
  Client: TClient;
  LQueue: TStringList;
  WQueue: TStringList;
begin
  Client := TClient(AContext.Data);
  // Send Cmd
  LQueue := nil;
  try
    WQueue := Client.QMsg.Lock;
    try
      if (WQueue.Count > 0) then
      begin
        LQueue := TStringList.Create;
        LQueue.Assign(WQueue);
        WQueue.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Client.QMsg.Unlock;
    end;
    if (LQueue <> nil) then
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LQueue);
  finally
    LQueue.Free;
  end;
  // Receive Data
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100) then Exit;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
  end;
  RStr := Trim(AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn);
  if (RStr <> '') then
  begin
    SyncLog(RStr);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you again Mr. Lebeau! Now it's time for me to try to understand your explanation and code :)