Client and server applications often crash with the Indy component
I can't find a solution to solve this problem.
The application works very well but when 4 or 5 clients start connecting and exchanging data at the same time,
The other clients currently exchanging data freeze and even the server freezes too.
I have already tried the critical section to prevent access to multiple and concurrent data but it doesn't change anything.
My big problem is that the application does not give errors that we catch with TRY EXCEPT but it freezes until forced closing in the task manager. I can't understand and trace the errors and the problem.
Do you have any idea what the problem is?
Please help me.
Server
procedure TServer.OnTCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
Var AClient: TClientInfo; AHeader: TTCPHeader; S: TStream;
    i: integer; AList: TList; JObj: TJSONObject; JSerialize: TJSONSerializer;
begin
   AClient.IP:= AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
   AClient.Port:= AContext.Binding.PeerPort;
   AClient.ID:= Integer(AContext);
   FListClient.Add(AClient);

   TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn).Thread.Synchronize(Procedure
   Begin
      If Assigned(FClientConnected) Then FClientConnected(AClient);
   End);

   //---------------------- Send Own ID --------------------
   AHeader.Command:= 103; // Connected
   AHeader.DataType:= 100; // Struct
   AHeader.DataSize:= SizeOf(TClientInfo);
   TRY
       S:= SerializeDataClient(AHeader, AClient);
       S.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
       AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
       AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(S, 0, True);
   FINALLY
       S.Free;
   END;

   //------ Send the list of clients connected and available to the network ---------
   if FListClient.Count > 1 then Begin
       TRY
          AHeader.Command:= 101; // List Client
          AHeader.DataType:= 101; // Liste
          AHeader.DataSize:= FListClient.Count-1;
          JObj:= TJSONObject.Create;
          JSerialize:= TJSONSerializer.Create;
          JObj.AddPair('Header', JSerialize.Serialize<TTCPHeader>(AHeader));
          For i:= 0 to FListClient.Count-1 Do Begin
              if FListClient.Items[i].ID <> Integer(AContext) then begin
                  AClient:= FListClient.Items[i];
                  JObj.AddPair('Data' + intTOstr(i), JSerialize.Serialize<TClientInfo>(AClient));
              end;
          End;
          JSerialize.Free;
          S:= TStringStream.Create(JObj.ToJSON);
          S.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(S, 0, True);
          S.Free;
       FINALLY
          JObj.Free;
       END;
   End;

   //--------- New Client Connecting?, Notify Other Clients already Connected --------------
   AHeader.Command:= 100; // Connected
   AHeader.DataType:= 100; // Struct
   AHeader.DataSize:= SizeOf(TClientInfo);
   AList:= FTCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
   For i:= 0 to AList.Count-1 Do Begin
       if TIDServerContext(AList.Items[i]) <> AContext then begin
          S:= SerializeDataClient(AHeader, AClient);
          S.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
          TRY
              FCS.Enter;
              TIDServerContext(AList.Items[i]).Connection.IOHandler.Write(S, 0, True);
          FINALLY
              FCS.Leave;
          END;
          S.Free;
       end;
   End;
   FTCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
end;

procedure TServer.OnTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var ASize: Int64; AHeader: TTCPHeader; JObj: TJSONObject; JSerialize: TJSONSerializer;
    i: Integer; AClient: TClientInfo; SData, AData, TData: TStringStream;
begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout:= 5000;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ConnectTimeout:= 5000;
    If AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1) AND AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Opened Then Begin
        TRY
            SData:= TStringStream.Create;
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(SData, -1, False);
            SData.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
            JObj:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(SData.DataString) as TJSONObject;
            JSerialize:= TJSONSerializer.Create;
            AHeader:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TTCPHeader>(JObj.GetValue('Header').Value);
            CASE AHeader.Command OF                
                1003: Begin // Data Stream From Client to Client                         
                             TRY
                                 TRY
                                    FCS.Enter;
                                    TData:= TStringStream.Create;
                                    TData.CopyFrom(SData, SData.Size);
                                    TData.Position:= 0;
                                    TIDServerContext(AHeader.IDDest).Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
                                    TIDServerContext(AHeader.IDDest).Connection.IOHandler.Write(TData, 0, True);
                                 FINALLY
                                    TData.Free;
                                    FCS.Leave;
                                 END;
                             EXCEPT
                                 On E: Exception Do Begin                                                    TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn).Thread.Synchronize(Procedure
                                     Begin
                                         if Assigned(FErrorEvent) Then FErrorEvent('WRITE - ' + E.Message);
                                     End);
                                 End;
                             END;
                      End;                
            END;
        FINALLY
            SData.Free;
            JSerialize.Free;
            JObj.Free;
        END;
    End;
end;

CLIENT
Procedure TClient.TaskResponse;
Begin
  FTaskResponse:= TTask.Create(Procedure
  Var ASize: Integer; AHeader: TTCPHeader;
      AClient: TClientInfo; AIndex, i: Integer; JObj: TJSONObject; JSerialize: TJSONSerializer;
      SData: TStringStream;
  Begin
      While FTaskResponse.Status = TTaskStatus.Running Do Begin
          TRY
              FTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadTimeout:= 5000;
              FTCPClient.IOHandler.ConnectTimeout:= 5000;
              If FTCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1) AND FTCPClient.IOHandler.Opened Then Begin
                  TRY
                      SData:= TStringStream.Create;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(SData, -1, False);
                      SData.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
                      JObj:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(SData.DataString) as TJSONObject;
                      SData.Free;
                      JSerialize:= TJSONSerializer.Create;
                      AHeader:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TTCPHeader>(JObj.GetValue('Header').Value);
                      CASE AHeader.Command OF
                          100: Begin // New Client Connected ?
                              AClient:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TClientInfo>(JObj.GetValue('Data').Value);
                              FListClient.Add(AClient);
                              TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                              Begin
                                 if Assigned(FClientConnected) then FClientConnected(AClient);
                              End);
                          End;

                          101: Begin // List Of clients Connected to Network
                              For i:= 0 to AHeader.DataSize-1 Do Begin
                                  AClient:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TClientInfo>(JObj.GetValue('Data' + intTOstr(i)).Value);
                                  FListClient.Add(AClient);
                                  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                                  Begin
                                      if Assigned(FClientConnected) then FClientConnected(AClient);
                                  End);
                              End;
                          End;

                          102: Begin // New Client DisConnected ?
                              AClient:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TClientInfo>(JObj.GetValue('Data').Value);
                              AIndex:= IndexOfContext(FListClient, AClient.ID);
                              FListClient.Delete(AIndex);
                              TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                              Begin
                                  if Assigned(FClientDisConnected) then FClientDisConnected(AClient);
                              End);
                          End;

                          103: Begin // Connected to Server
                              AClient:= JSerialize.Deserialize<TClientInfo>(JObj.GetValue('Data').Value);
                              FStatusConnection:= scConnected;
                              FMyID:= AClient;
                              TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                              Begin
                                  if Assigned(FConnected) then FConnected(AClient);
                              End);
                          End;
                          
                          1003: Begin  // Data Stream from Client
                              for i:= 0 to FListClient.Count-1 do begin
                                  if FListClient.Items[i].ID = AHeader.IDSource Then Begin
                                      AClient:= FListClient.Items[i];
                                      Break;
                                  End;
                              end;
                              TRY
                                  SData:= TStringStream.Create(TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(JObj.GetValue('Data').Value));
                                  SData.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
                                  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                                  Begin
                                      if Assigned(FReceiveDataStreamClientEvent) then FReceiveDataStreamClientEvent(AClient, SData);
                                  End);
                              FINALLY
                                  SData.Free;
                              END;
                          End;
                          1004: Begin  // Data Stream from Server

                          End;
                      END;
                  FINALLY
                    JSerialize.Free;
                    JObj.Free;
                  END;
              End Else If Not FTCPClient.IOHandler.Opened Then Begin
                  While Assigned(FTCPClient.IOHandler) Do Begin
                      FListClient.Clear;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.CloseGracefully;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.Close;
                      FreeAndNil(FTCPClient.IOHandler);
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler:= NIL;
                      FStatusConnection:= scDisConnected;
                      If Assigned(FTaskResponse) Then Begin
                          TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                          Begin
                              if Assigned(FDisConnected) then FDisConnected(Self);
                          End);
                          FTaskResponse.Cancel;
                      End;
                  End;
              End;
             // end;
          EXCEPT
              On E: EIdReadTimeOut Do Begin
                  if Assigned(FErrorEvent) Then FErrorEvent('READ - ' + E.Message);
              End;

              On E: EIdConnClosedGracefully Do Begin
                  if Assigned(FErrorEvent) Then FErrorEvent('READ - ' + E.Message);
                  While Assigned(FTCPClient.IOHandler) Do Begin
                      FListClient.Clear;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.CloseGracefully;
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler.Close;
                      FreeAndNil(FTCPClient.IOHandler);
                      FTCPClient.IOHandler:= NIL;
                      FStatusConnection:= scDisConnected;
                      If Assigned(FTaskResponse) Then Begin
                          TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, Procedure
                          Begin
                              if Assigned(FDisConnected) then FDisConnected(Self);
                          End);
                          FTaskResponse.Cancel;
                      End;
                  End;
              End;

              On E: EIdException Do Begin
                  if Assigned(FErrorEvent) Then FErrorEvent('READ - ' + E.Message);
              End;
          END;
      End;
  End);
  FTaskResponse.Start;
End;

Procedure TClient.SendToClient(AClient: TClientInfo; AData: TStream); // Send Stream to Another Client on network
var AHeader: TTCPHeader; S: TStream;
Begin
    AHeader.Command:= 1003;
    AHeader.DataType:= 1;
    AHeader.DataSize:= AData.Size;
    AHeader.IDDest:= AClient.ID;
    AHeader.IDSource:= FMyID.ID;
    S:= SerializeDataStream(AHeader, AData);
    if FTCPClient.IOHandler.Connected AND FTCPClient.IOHandler.Opened Then Begin
        TRY
            FTCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream:= True;
            FTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(S, 0, True);
        EXCEPT
            On E: EIdException Do Begin
                if Assigned(FErrorEvent) Then FErrorEvent('WRITE - ' + E.Message);
            End;
        END;
    End;
    S.Free;
End;


I wanted to create an application that exchanges data in Stream between clients. It's like Messenger chats but that's not the end goal.

What you describe is a deadlock, not a crash. Each client runs in its own thread, so any synchronization between threads is your responsibility. For example, access to FListClient needs to be synchronized (BTW,TIdTCPServer already has a thread-safe Contexts list - you can store custom data in the TIdContext.Data property). Also, your code lacks many try..finally blocks to ensure any thread locks are unlocked properly in case an error does occur...

... Also, you have code that potentially writes to a given client socket from multiple threads at the same time. That needs to be synchronized, too (your FCS is not adequate for that job).  It's best NOT to write directly to a client across threads (especially when sending unsolicited messages, as you are), but instead to queue any outgoing messages for a client and let the client's own OnExecute event pick up its queued messages and send them when safe to do so. I've posted examples of that before.

You will need to add LOGGING to your code and debug it yourself.  Start by using OutputDebugString.
I would never want to debug this but for sure the first thing I would start logging is everywhere you free, and everywhere you allocate, and everywhere you're using Synchronize, before and after.

I followed your advice, I stored the client information in the AContext.Data, I removed the sending of unsolicited messages in the onExecute, I put it in another thread in a queue. and finally I added the logging to trace the errors. the result is better than before. It no longer blocks for 8 clients who exchange data at the same time but after 10 clients. The problem comes back, the clients and server block.

@DominiqueRinaRAJAOFERSON Then I suggest you update your question with the latest code you are still having trouble with. Also, "I removed the sending of unsolicited messages in the onExecute" - I didn't say to remove unsolicited  messages, just to not write them directly to a socket from outside of the OnExecute event. The OnExecute event should be doing all of the writing to its AContext's socket. "I put it in another thread in a queue" - that sounds suspicious.

@Remy Lebeau I didn't understand, can you show an example, how to send an unsolicited message inside onExecute?

@DominiqueRinaRAJAOFERSON here are a few examples I've posted in past answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106069/65863, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612675/65863, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061527/65863

@Remy Lebeau, I followed the example in these links, the problem is solved, thank you very much.
